# Is it possible to compile Darwin on Linux

Tags: linux, compile, darwin

since i don't want to buy a new overpriced mac or try "Hackintosh" which is really time consuming so is it possible to compile Darwin in Linux

Comment: You can download it - http://www.puredarwin.org - but it's not exactly a finished desktop OS.

Comment: actually im working on this [https://superuser.com/questions/546151/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-darwin-distro-from-source-like-you-can-a-build-a-li] so i really need to compile it

Comment: Then it's simply a duplicate of that question & the answer is the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to compile a Darwin Distro from source, like you can a build a Linux Distro?](https://superuser.com/questions/546151/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-darwin-distro-from-source-like-you-can-a-build-a-li)

Comment: no it says you need a mac

Comment: Then that's still probably the correct answer. It's probably even less likely you could do it with newer versions of Darwin. As the answer points out, you need the kexts & they're not available.

Comment: btw, if you want it to run Mac apps, don't bother. What you'll end up with is not a Mac, but a half-baked unix command line.

Comment: You're asking the same question. Not liking the other answer doesn't mean your question isn't a duplicate.